# Rbind, updated variable name for list$ in for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, rbind

I am collecting lists from google trends with a loop. I know want to use a second loop to rbind the $trend data.frame from each list (I have 62 lists).

Instead of doing it with one rbind over all 62 lists (like rbind(list1$trend, list2trend, ..., list62$trend) I want to do it in a more elegant loop.

I tried it with the code below, but it is not working. I get the following error message:

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Here is the code I am using. Any help is really appreciated! Thanks a lot!

```
 trend = list1$trend
    i=2
    for (i in 4) {
      list <- paste("list", i, sep = "")
      list <- (paste(list, "$trend", sep=""))
      rbind(trend, list)
    }
```

Comment: `do.call('rbind', lapply(list1, '[[', 'trend'))` maybe? please make this reproducible

Answer (score 1):

Use the `rbindlist()` from the `data.table` package. Rbind in a loop is horribly inefficient as the size of the data frame gets redefined with each binding event. If you don't want to stay with the data.table format you can just wrap it in `data.frame()`. Happy to provide some code if the question gets updated with a reproducible example.

Comment: To extract the trend data.frame from the list you can follow rawr's comment above but do `rbindlist(lapply(list1, '[[', 'trend'))`